# Every time I connect to the internet zenity says "downloading wine-unity3d-installer"

Tags: wine, downloads, zenity

Every time I connect to the internet Zenity flashes that little popup for about a second (because the download is apparently 1 mb) a couple of times. First of all, why does it keep installing the same installer over and over and over? And secondly, is there any way to make it stop stealing the focus every time it comes up? Or better yet stop this downloading business. (By stealing focus I mean that every time this popup occurs it switches the focus to it and makes it the top window, even if I'm in a game, it'll tab out and show the window. Very annoying) Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have Pipelight installed? If so, please try executing this command: `sudo pipelight-plugin --disable unity3d`. This would disable Unity 3D.

Comment: that might be it! I'll run it now, after a while if it stops I'll edit this.

Answer (score 3):

Its just because the plugin db provided with Pipelight 0.2.4.2 isn't up-to-date anymore. To update it manually:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update


sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins

(clear plugin cache (only necessary for using Firefox))
```

Afterwards it should work.

[[source: http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation-comments-1.html ]]